# Does single swap rule apply to in-the-plane bonds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

When forming enantiomers, does the single swap rule (swapping 2 of the atoms directly bonded to a chiral C will give its enantiomer) apply, even when we're switching bonds that are in the plane?

For example, swapping a wedge and a dash gives the enantiomer; swapping the dash and an in-the-plane bond gives the enantiomer etc, but what about two in-the-plane bonds? Does this give the enantiomer too?

Comment: Yes it does. Think of it this way: the molecule is real, but the plane only exists in our imagination. Can you imagine a different plane, so that the bonds which were in the plane become wedge-and-dash, and vice versa? Of course you can. Well, the molecule is still the same.

Comment: If your molecule has more than one element of chirality, then switching  two bonds at only one center will lead to an optically active diastereomer, not an enantiomer.